# SCSS and Compass CLI configuration

Tags: compass-sass, sass

How do I configure Compass when using the `sass` CLI?

Basically I was to set the `images_dir` property, here is the command I have been using:

```
sass 
    --compass
    path/to/input.scss
    path/to/output.css
```

I tried:

```
sass 
    --compass
    -c path/to/config.rb
    path/to/input.scss
    path/to/output.css
```

Output:

```
WARNING on line 1 of path/to/config.rb:
This selector doesn't have any properties and will not be rendered.
Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "image_dir ": expected selector, was "= "test""
    on line 1 of path/to/config.rb
```

So obviously the `-c` doesn't work the same way when using the `compass compile` command.

And

```
sass 
    --compass
    --images-dir path/to/images
    path/to/input.scss
    path/to/output.css
```

Output:

```
OptionParser::InvalidOption: invalid option: --images-dir
```

Likewise as above.

I tried to use the `compass compile` but I don't have a project directory.

```
compass compile 
    --images-dir path/to/images
    path/to
    path/to/input.scss
```

Output:

```
You must compile individual stylesheets from the project directory.
```

Also tried this:

```
compass compile 
    path/to
```

Output:

```
Nothing to compile. If you're trying to start a new project, you have left off the directory argument.
```

config.rb just contained:

```
images_dir = "test"
```

Comment: What's in your config.rb file?

Comment: Also, what output are you getting?

Comment: Compass has its own command:  `compass watch` or `compass create`.  Try `compass --help` for more options.

Comment: @cimmanon I tried using that command to no avail (updated question)

Comment: Have you tried `--images_dir` instead of `--images-dir`?

Comment: @tristanm yep, same deal `compass help compile` says its `--images-dir` though.

Comment: You may want to consider consulting the docs before jumping straight to SO:  http://compass-style.org/install/.  None of the things you've tried are listed in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`compass compile` reads a `config.rb` file for the configuration.

Here is an example project setup that that I use, starting with the `config.rb` file:

```
require "susy"

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "public/css"
sass_dir = "private/scss"
images_dir = "public/images"
http_images_path = "/images"

output_style = :expanded # or :nested or :compact or :compressed

# To disable debugging comments that display the original location of your selectors. Uncomment:
line_comments = true
```

My project is setup like:

```
private/scss    # scss files. I use a main file that handles imports itself
public/images   # images
public/css      # built css here
config.rb       # contents included above
```

To build it, I run the following in the project's root folder:

```
bundle exec compass compile private/scss/layout.scss
```